# How to know if a user is new after ditching parse.com

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm getting rid of parse.com altogether
and i don't want users that are upgrading to the new version of the app to go through the signup page again

I can assume that all the users that owned the previous version don't need to go through the signup.

I previously used the "if ([PFUser currentUser])" to know if the user should go through the signup

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting rid of parse.com altogether and i don't want users that are upgrading to the new version of the app to go through the signup page again

One way is to issue an updated app that still includes Parse so that you can use it to transfer users to some other system. For example, if `[PFUser currentUser]` returns `YES`, store some chunk of data with CloudKit or AWS or whatever you decide to use. Once that update has been out for a while, you can issue another update that actually removes Parse and relies on the presence of that data to determine that the user can skip signing up.